# Indented TabLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-tablayout

In TabLayout, how can I set left indent? Like for example AdSense google app.

[image]

Comment: `<android.support.design.widget.TabItem 
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
             android:text="@string/tab_text"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **`app:tabContentStart="100dp"`** for to give indent

This attribute allows you **move the active tab to the left** according to the value specified, which is set in "dp" (like a margin-left thing)

Comment: hope this is helpfull

Comment: Thanks! It is just what I needed.